# How can if fix error: threefry.h: No such file or directory in Docker?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a docker container using rocker and a homebrew package. I have no troubles installing my homebrew package on my desktop. Alas, when I try to install it in the container I get the following error:

```
2 -g  -c predict_rcpp.cpp -o predict_rcpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dqrng/include/dqrng_distribution.h:26:0,
                 from predict_rcpp.cpp:5:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dqrng/include/dqrng_generator.h:27:10: fatal error: threefry.h: No such file or directory
 #include <threefry.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:176: recipe for target 'predict_rcpp.o' failed
make: *** [predict_rcpp.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘SLPRcpp’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/SLPRcpp’
Warning message:
In install.packages(pkgs = f, lib = lib, repos = if (isMatchingFile(f)) NULL else repos) :
  installation of package ‘SLPRcpp_2.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm guessing I'm missing dependency but I'm not sure what it is. How can I debug this?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  #git-core \ 
  #libcurl4-gnutls-dev \ 
  #libssl-dev \ 
  libxml2-dev \
  librandom123-dev \
  r-cran-bh \ 
  r-cran-dplyr \ 
  #r-cran-ggiraph \ 
  r-cran-ggplot2 \ 
  r-cran-glue \ 
  r-cran-httr \ 
  r-cran-magrittr \ 
  r-cran-plumber \ 
  r-cran-purrr \ 
  r-cran-r6 \ 
  r-cran-rcpp \ 
  #r-cran-rcppArmadillo \ 
  #r-cran-rcppEigen \ 
  r-cran-readr \ 
  r-cran-rstan \ 
  r-cran-rstantools \ 
  r-cran-scales \ 
  #r-cran-stanHeaders \ 
  r-cran-stringr \
  r-cran-shiny \
  r-cran-tidyr \
  r-cran-dqrng

RUN install.r ggiraph RcppArmadillo RcppEigen StanHeaders 

# Install SLPRcpp package
COPY SLPRcpp_2.6.tar.gz /SLPRcpp_2.6.tar.gz
RUN install.r SLPRcpp_2.6.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dqrng` requires the `sitmo` package, c.f. https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng, which includes the `threefry.h` header. It is a bug in the `r-cran-dqrng` package if it doesn’t pull in `r-cran-sitmo`. However, this does not seem to be the case:

```
dpkg-deb --info r-cran-dqrng_0.2.1-1cran1ppabionic0_amd64.deb | grep Depends
 Depends: r-base-core, r-cran-rcpp, r-cran-bh, r-cran-sitmo, libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the reason has to be in your package. Most likely your package does not have `LinkingTo: sitmo` in it. This is required for using (some of) the headers, though:

> The RNG wrapper and distributions functions can be used from C++ by including dqrng_generator.h and dqrng_distribution.h. In order to use these header files, you have to use at least C++11 and link to the BH and sitmo packages as well.
>
> Source: https://www.daqana.org/dqrng/articles/dqrng.html#using-the-header-only-library

I do not understand why your package works outside of Docker, though.

Comment: LinkingTo may not translate to Depends. Talk to Michael.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. I added `r-cran-sitmo` but I still have the same error. The next thing that I'm trying is moving from `rocker/r-ubuntu` to `rocker/r-base`. Alas, building the container takes much longer. I will report back if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @Ignacio: Step back, take a moment, and think this through.  Swapping Rocker containers has exactly *zero* impact on your problem, and the underlying issue has been explained here.

Comment: @Ralf  Good.  We're not that bad then :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralf and Max. I have learned many valuable lessons this morning. Linking to `sitmo` did the trick.

Comment: So who is Max ?

Comment: I meant to write Dirk. Thanks Dirk! I really appreciate your help. Max is someone I work with that is probably sleeping because is Saturday morning

Answer (score 2):

Use the [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) webpage which you can search by file as well.

Here is the result [when searching for threefry.h](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=threefry.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) -- you want `librandom123-dev`.

By the way, this has zero to do with Rcpp and I will edit out the tag.  Next time consider asking such a question at https://askubuntu.com/.  (It also has zero to do with `installr` which AFAIK is for installing on Windows.)

Comment: Thanks for the help Dirk and sorry for asking this in the wrong place. Alas, I added `librandom123-dev` to my dockerfile and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you read the DESCRIPTION of `dqrng`? It says it needs `sitmo`.  Do you have `sitmo`?

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I didn't think of checking the DESCRIPTION for dependencies because I was trusting apt to do that for me. Lesson learned. Alas, I added `r-cran-sitmo` as suggested by Ralf and the error did not go away.

Comment: Because you were confusing package dependencies at the OS (required, not sufficient) with package dependencies at the application level -- your issue was a simple bug in your package and had zero to do with either Docker, Rocker, Rcpp, installr or anything else.  Don't feel bad -- most bugs are like that and we all had our fair share.  The key is to _simplify_ and by randomly throwing Docker containers around you ... more or less did the opposite.